# How to implement spell checking on Android with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, spell-checking

Coming from an iOS dev background, working on a custom android keyboard. I am trying to implement spell checking into the keyboard, but don't know how to do it.

I found the [Spell checker framework](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/spell-checker-framework), but how I understood it, this framework only provides the blank abstract methods, while I need to implement spell checking myself. (Why..? If I created my own spell checker, surely I can make my own abstract methods to call it...)

I also figured out spell checking like so:

```kotlin
val textServicesManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE) as TextServicesManager
val mSpellCheckerSession = textServicesManager.newSpellCheckerSession(null, null, mSpellCheckerSessionListener, true)
```

and then calling it with

```kotlin
mSpellCheckerSession?.getSuggestions(TextInfo("misspelled words"), 5)
```

But this method is asynchronous and I have to listen for results with  `onGetSuggestions`. This won't work for me, since my keyboard needs to spell check and correct users on the fly, after the word is typed. So I need a synchronous method.

On iOS we simply have [UITextChecker()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextchecker) from which we can synchronously ask for spelling corrections. Is there anything like that on Android? How can I get synchronous spelling suggestions?

Comment: Unclear if you've seen the AOSP project linked at the end of your first link, LatinIME https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/ and more specifically https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/refs/heads/main/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/spellcheck/

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you're writing spell check into the IME, you don't use the spell checker framework.  That's really of use if you want to link in an external library doing it at an application level.  For an IME, you generally just do spell checking on your own.  There is no requirement for an IME to use it.

Instead, after every letter is tapped (or swiped, or whatever other input method you're using), you'd feed the context around the cursor into whatever algorithm you wrote, take the suggestions returned, and display them (generally in a suggestions bar, although that also is up to you).

Comment: I had assumed Android would have a standard built-in library for spell checking, like we do on iOS. If not, what are some good options?

Comment: No, every keyboard does their own, because they all think they can do it better.  That's one of the main reasons to use a different keyboard-  better prediction. How would the OS know the best spell check algorithm-  even if it assumes you're typing and not swiping or some other input method, it doesn't even know the layout of your keyboard.  If you make the same guesses for qwerty and dvorak, or even qwerty and azerty, you're going to have bad predictions.

Comment: Also, the spell checker framework you asked about is consumed by the OS, to provide corrections in the Android UI.  Generally that's used by their grammar and spell corrections for already typed data rather than on the fly spelling correction (ever seen a word red underlined that you had previously typed?  Spell checker framework in action).

Comment: Understood, thank you, I will look for solutions. In response to your point though: I think you misunderstood what I am talking about. The OS does not need to know which best spell check algorithm to use, what input method is used, or what type of keyboard you use. What I am talking about is what we have on iOS - a built in implementation of a single spell check algorithm, which you can use anywhere: keyboard, front-end app, text-field, or whatever. Your provide misspelled text - you get back possible corrections. I was hoping there a built-in framework for that on Android, but apparently no.

Comment: @GrantOganyan I didn't misunderstand, I was telling you *why* it doesn't do that.  Because the philosophy is rather than providing a mediocre implementation, the keyboard is its own app and should return a *good* implementation.

Comment: Your rhetorical questions did indicate lack of understanding of my problem, since they were irrelevant. Your reasoning as to "why" is also impractical: "rather than providing a mediocre implementation..." - why not ship Android with a good built-in implementation, while still allowing others to create their own? Your statement is analogous to "lets not include a calculator app into the OS, because third-party devs will create a better one".

Comment: @GrantOganyan Because a good implementation is impossible with the keyboard being a separate app, there's too much it doesn't know.  If you'd ever written one, you'd realize that.  And quite frankly it would be a waste of their resources to do-  there's 0 reason that spell check should be part of an operating system.

Comment: BTW, I did soft keyboards professionally for 4 years and know people still in that area-  no serious keyboard uses the built in iOS stuff.  They all roll their own.  It's only used by basically people writing their own toy apps.

Comment: I have written one, and actually two, also professionally. So don't bother flexing, you only humiliate yourself, especially when you don't know who is sitting on the other side. There are plenty reasons for spell check to be a part of the OS, just like any other framework. Otherwise, we'd all be writing binary. If you think something should not exist because "its not too good, I can do better" then its your own problem. Refer to my previous comment about the calculator. I am not going to entertain your delusions any more.

Comment: @GrantOganyan If you think the built in one is any good, then no, you haven't. The very fact that you had to ask this question means no, you haven't.